# Mac Not Saving Passphrase for SSH Keys

Tags: macos, ssh, keychain

I have tried everything for my passphrase to be saved for my SSH keys so that when I restart, I don't have to run any "ssh-add" command.

I have tried:

- Saving my key in ~/.ssh
- Saving my key in ~/.ssh/id_rsa (it is an RSA key)
- Making a profile for it in ~/.ssh/config
- Running "sudo ssh-key -k ~/.ssh/keyname" and "sudo ssh-key -K ~/.ssh/keyname" and those commands using the ~/.ssh/id_rsa directory whenever the key was in that place
- Probably a few other things, but all I can remember at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I renamed the key to "id_rsa", instead of the actual name of the key, which I thought I had already tried, but after I did that, it worked.